# you don't have an extension for debugging groovy in flutter using visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, groovy

I have this problem in my flutter app and when I try to find a Groovy extension in Vs code there is no extension (picture 2) !

[image]

Here when I click on find Groovy extension there is nothing!

[image]

Please anyone who faces this problem and find a solution for it tell me

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You must have hit "Run" while your IDE focus was on the `build.gradle` file instead of any `.dart` file. That's why it's trying to find a Groovy extension.

Just click on your `main.dart` or any other dart file, and try to Run your app again.

Comment: Thanks ! it works

Comment: @sm66 I'm glad it worked. If this solved your problem, would you mind marking the answer as the accepted answer please? Thanks!